# Слетает кириллица gRPC .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, docker, grpc, .net-5, blazor-client-side

Бэк gRPC , фронт Blazor , .NET 5.0

При запуске в винде и виндовом докере все нормально.
Когда разворачиваю в докере на VPS (ubuntu) то на самой странице текст русский, а вот то что приходит из gRPC становится �����.

Понятное дело что беда с кодировкой, но я не понимаю, что именно не так уже кончились идеи.

locale в ubuntu

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

locale в докере

```
# locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru_RU:ru
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Сначала думал что проблема при сериализации, но дефолтный HelloRequest ведет себя так же.
У кого то было такое?

Ради интереса развернул minimal APIs .NET6 в докере - эффект тот же. Русский текст в ответе становится ���� . На Win11 все нормально текст русский.

Еще кстати если gRPC юзать как обычное api и добавить в endpoints.MapGet такую строку `context.Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8";` то он возвращает из vps на русском без вопросиков. Но если юзать запросы через stream - не нашел где можно это указать

Беру данные так

```
using var serverStream = GreeterClient.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest());
var stream = await serverStream.ResponseAsync;
var result = stream.Message;
```

Comment: Ответа не знаю, знаю только что в винде кодировка по умолчанию не UTF-8, а Unicode (UTF-16). Но вряд-ли это как-то связано с проблемой.

Comment: _если юзать запросы через stream_ - с этого места поподробнее.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, Добавил пример запроса через stream.

Comment: aepot, попробовал из utf16 в utf8 по разному и из protobuf encoding получаю - ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½,
����,
����,
����

Comment: Мне тут сказали что - "Возможно, языковая поддержка была удалена из приложения, чтобы уменьшить размер загрузки." Кто-то знает как это можно проверить?

Answer (score 3):

Это смешно, но файл действительно был закодирован в кодировке 1251.
В моем проекте Blazor WebAssembly файлы *.razor UTF8, но файлы gRPC - 1251, теперь понятно, почему это происходит... Но непонятно, почему VS создает файлы в разных кодировках.

Используя notepad++, я сделал его utf8, и все сработало.

Чтобы исправить это для новых файлов, мне пришлось сделать этот параметр
Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Save documents as Unicode